# How to write / read a temporary file within the same script using sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, text-parsing

I'm using `sed` to correct a two column PDF (using `pdftotext` 3.03) conversion issue.  The converter will at times work properly (left column text prints first, then right column text prints second).  However, sometimes it will break at a hyphen in the text and switch into printing text in a `^left column + right column$` format.

I thought to solve this by printing out all the left column text to `stdout` and building a multiline hold space with the right column text which I would switch into the pattern space and output to `stdout` later.  However, I found several conversion correction cases requiring that I used the hold space for the fix.

Instead, I attempted to try and dump the right column text into a external file (rtcol.txt) temporarily so that I can later retrieve it.  But I seem to be having problems getting the contents of the file to print to the screen.  I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `sed` may still have the file open and has yet to write the cached text into it.  Please see the following partial pseudo code example:

```
                      # Example of complicated case when hyphen causes a multiline issue
/regex to 1st line/ { h; s/ignored ltcol.*\(capture rtcol txt.*\).*- \(more rtcol.*$\)/\1\2/w rtcol.txt
                      x; s/\(capture ltcol.*\)ignore rtcol.*\(more ltcol.*\)-.*/\1\2/;
                      N; s/\(.*\)\n\(Get more ltcol from next line.*\)/\1\2/p; d; 
                    }

                      # Section where converter at least separated the lines (ltcol \n rtcol)
/regex to next fix/ { n; p; n; w rtcol.txt
                      
                      # Section where converter simply added the two lines (ltcol + rtcol)
                      n; s/^\(ltcol.*\) \(rtcol.*\)$/\1\n\2/; P; s/[^\n]*\n//w rtcol.txt
                    }

                      # After final correction, try to print out temp file contents
/regex to last fix/ { n; p; n; w rtcol.txt
                      r rtcol.txt
                    }
```

At first, I thought this was a `sed` [limitation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html#Limitations) on the number of UTF-8 characters you can execute.  But currently I'm using ~1900 bytes in the temp file, and I tried to save the temp file into another file and it worked (even though that file was not dynamically created as I desired).

So, my question is this: can you write to a file and pull its contents within the same script?  Is there a way to force `sed` to sync the cached text to the file and then read from it?  Or should I look to use a different type of program (e.g. `awk`) or approach for this conversion correction process?

`sed --version` is `sed (GNU sed) 4.7` in Debian 11

Comment: With GNU sed, you can always use `e cat rtcol.txt` and see if that works.   Also I note that your pseudocode has rtcol3 in one place, which would result in some omitted text.

Comment: @KJ, thanks for the advice for other PDF conversion tool.  I will check them out.
@stevesliva, I tried the `e cat rtcol.txt` command and the result is the same.  Like trying to print out an empty file, but if I use a pre-populated file, then it works.  And I'll edit my pseudocode :)

Comment: @KJ, your skills with pdftotext and other tools is impressive.  Thanks for the examples.  I will try [xpdf's](https://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html) pdftotext and see what it turns out for me.  The way I'm running the [poppler's](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/poppler-utils/pdftotext.1.en.html) is as follows (let me know if I could use a different option or something): `pdftotext -y 130 -W 700 -H 560 <PDF file> -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to find the answer to this question.

At first, I thought it was a [limitation of sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html#Limitations) where the pattern space could only hold so many characters (per the link, only 4000 bytes).  But in my application, using UTF-8 encoding (1 byte per character) I only got to around 2000 bytes max.

Decided to do some source code diving, and found that `GNU sed` does indeed have a [flush output function](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_sed/blob/master/sed/execute.c#L426).  Did a quick search on sed about flushing output and found this [stack overflow post by @Naab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030127/21495068) (give credit where due).  And sure enough found that `-u` option in the [source code](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_sed/blob/master/sed/sed.c#L348) as well.

So for future reference, if you need to use external files as a temp storage for file parsing, make sure to add the `-u` flag as below (not exceeding 4000 bytes):

```
pdftotext -y 130 -W 700 -H 560 <PDF File> - | sed -n -u -f script.sed
```

Comment: Not sure where the comments from @KJ went to.  But changing the option for the [poppler's pdftotext](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/poppler-utils/pdftotext.1.en.html) (particularly the `-raw` option) helped to fix the conversion issue into a much more usable state.  Thanks sir!